# Video Scene Detection for .Net windows app

Tags: .net, video, computer-vision, tracking, surveillance

I'm trying to do scene detection on video files.

I want to take a video file as an input and i want to detect scene changes and also tell me at what positions are scene changes happening.

I'm happy to use 3rd party libraries to do this, but I'm not sure where to start.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly [EmguCV (OpenCV .net wrapper)](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) can fulfill your needs. Here is [video surveillance module](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/947e83c8-ab88-c8ce-6a89-41235860d12a.htm).

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're not using a 3rd party library, you need to examine each frame (or series of frames) in turn and determine how different they are. This is a non-trivial task and ususally either requires some complex math (to detect panning/movement) or some interesting neural net stuff. If you're new to this, a 3rd party component seems the way to go.

The [Victor Image Processing Library](http://www.catenary.com/) claims to do what you need (by calculating a coefficient between 2 images) but I've never used it so can't comment on how good it is.

Comment: Looks like this is meant for Image processing. Went to their site and did not found anything related to video.I am looking for detecting video scenes...

Comment: @ProblemSolver The relevant article is here: http://www.catenary.com/howto/motion.html